# How did the Backup EMH make the journey back to the Alpha Quadrant without the mobile emitter?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-voyager, star-trek-emh

When he was activated at the beginning of VOY: Living Witness he obviously has no mobile emitter since he is a backup copy. He is also seen outside of the holo-recreation of Voyager and walking around the museum.

How was he able to do this (and then make a journey back to the Alpha Quadrant) with no mobile emitter?

Comment: I haven't seen that one in ages - but wasn't the museum equipped with holo-emitters, and wasn't his mobile emitter one of the museum pieces anyway?

Comment: It's possible the museum probably was, there was only one mobile emitter and the  real doctor made it home with that

Comment: Ahh... very good point. I wonder if it's possibly given the fact the species seemed very advanced in that episode, they were able to re-create it from the data they had from Voyager (they got the characters wrong admittedly, but technology probably would have been a doddle to do) - but I'm just guessing and can't think of any canon - so I'll shut up :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The museum contains an extensive holographic simulation that the Kyrians have been using to show their dubiously sourced *historical* tableaux. The emitters (which we see within the display) seem to have enough range to project the Doctor's holo-matrix out into the main body of the museum.

[image]

Given that the Kyrians evidently have ready access to holo-emitting technology and that this technology is sufficiently mature that they're able to install it in a small regional museum, it's hardly surprising that they were able to fit out a spaceworthy vessel with those same emitters.

Comment: Even if they fitted the shuttle with holo emitters it seems risky taking a trip that could last decades relying on them when most likely something would go wrong at some point in the journey

Comment: @Darren - That's very true, but with only one passenger and no crew needing life-support, just think of all the extra space you could have for backup emitters and spare holographic drives

Comment: Or, not bother with emitters at all. The projection's primary purpose is interaction with people in the same physical space. Flying along by himself, he wouldn't need to do that if he could control the ship directly (as software). The holographic capabilities of the mobile emitter are impressive, but the computational capacity required to run a sapient AI in a box not much bigger than a cigarette lighter is more impressive.

Comment: @T.J.L. - That's quite true. If he fitted out a shuttle like it's a type 9 probe (basically a gigantic fuel tank) and just lodged himself as software inside the ship's memory then he could chug along at warp 9.999 for weeks or even months.

Comment: The mobile emitter was technology from the 29th century. The events in this episode take place 700 years after voyager, which would be the 31st century. So they could very likely have technology *more advanced* than the mobile emitter.

Comment: @Dennis_E - The Federation might, but don't forget that the Kyrians aren't in the Federation. As far as we can tell, their technology in the 31st century seems to be on a par with Federation technology in the 24th century or even before.